# Permissions to execute CLR Triggers

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have inherited an application with CLR triggers and am trying to migrate the Database to another server.

My application user has `db_owner` on the Database but when it executes I get an error.

This appears to be permission related because when I elevate the app user to be a `sysadmin`, everything fires correctly.

But that seems like a super horrible "fix".

The source server also has the user as a `sysadmin` so I'm guessing they couldn't sort it out either. Just for fun I gave the user `db_owner` on the system tables as well since it appears its trying to read locks and other `sys` table items. Still no luck.

What permissions need to be granted to a user in order for them to execute a `SAFE CLR` trigger?

This trigger appears to be used for auditing. It fires when certain data has changed and records the difference, inspecting the inserted and deleted tables and query which tables have locks in order to determine where the activity is occurring.

Comment: Please post the exact error message. This is too vague to answer at the moment. There shouldn't be anything special needed if the SQLCLR Trigger is in an Assembly marked as `SAFE`. Though have you checked to make sure that the SID of the dbo user in that database is the same SID as the one listed in `sys.databases`?

Comment: And what does the Trigger do? Does it do any DML? If so, it could be an ownership-chaining issue. Which is easy enough to fix by signing the Assembly, creating an Asymmetric Key (or Certificate), a Login based on that Key, and granting it the proper permissions. With more info (i.e. the error message and what the Trigger is doing), I can give more precise instructions.

Comment: Also, try granting `VIEW SERVER STATE` to your app user. That is required to view lock info (at least via `sys.dm_tran_locks` ) and I don't think putting someone in the `db_owner` role will get you there.

Comment: I did not include the error because it was vague suggesting to rewrite as nested transactions and the whole something failed inside something else, inside a transaction. I did not want to get caught up in that error since it was misleading and I knew it could function with elevated permissions.

Comment: @srutzky - Can you please make your last comment regarding Server State an answer so that I may mark it as correct. Also add in from your first: "There shouldn't be anything special needed" since this also addresses my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a purely-SQLCLR perspective, there shouldn't be any special permissions needed for Assemblies marked as `SAFE`. Assemblies marked as either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE` require a little bit of extra setup. There are, however, two permissions-related issues to look at:

1. All T-SQL submitted from within SQLCLR objects is, by its very nature of coming from application code and being submitted on-the-fly (and hence not pre-processed), Dynamic SQL. And Dynamic SQL breaks the ownership chain that otherwise allows the execution of a Stored Procedure to infer the permissions for the underlying objects. This is easy enough to fix by doing:

   - Sign the Assembly / DLL
   - Create an Asymmetric Key in the Database containing the Assembly FROM the Assembly
   - Create a User in the Database containing the Assembly FROM the Asymmetric Key
   - Grant the new User the appropriate permissions for the objects accessed in the Trigger
   - When the Trigger executes, it will inherit the permissions of this new User

   **However, it is probably not the case that this is the actual issue since you have placed your app User into the `db_owner` database role, which should have permission to access all objects in the database (assuming no explicit `DENY`s are in place).**
2. Since you mention that the Trigger is looking at lock info, assuming that is coming from [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx), then the app Login needs the `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission which is server-level (hence app Login and not app User, which is database-level). I doubt placing a User in the `db_owner` database role would infer this permission because that role is confined to the database. You also mention that adding the Login to the `sysadmin` server role allows the Trigger to work, which appears to be further evidence that this is the probably the real issue.